# unable to execute query

Tags: php, mysql, select

Can somebody help me with this query.The page doesn't load up whenever i run this query.I'm pretty much sure its something really simple mistake which I'm unable to figure out.Your help is much appreciated.

```
$aggr_nr = $_REQUEST['stck_list_nr_01'].$_REQUEST['stck_list_nr_02'].$_REQUEST['stck_list_nr_03'];
echo $aggr_nr;

$sql="SELECT v.id FROM vers_einl_aggregatnummer AS v WHERE v.aggr_nr = $aggr_nr";
$aggr_id = mysql_query($sql);

if ($aggr_id == true)
 {
        echo "query 1 executed".$aggr_id;
    else  
    {
    echo("<br />Could not execute statement ".$sql);
    }
 }
```

Comment: There are several issues .. the query .. the result type .. the if/then/else braces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//sanitize the inputs 
$aggr_nr = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['stck_list_nr_01'].$_REQUEST['stck_list_nr_02'].$_REQUEST['stck_list_nr_03']);
 echo $aggr_nr;

$sql="SELECT v.id FROM vers_einl_aggregatnummer AS v WHERE v.aggr_nr = '".$aggr_nr."'";//missing Quotes
$aggr_id = mysql_query($sql);

if ($aggr_id) {
 while($result = mysql_fetch_array($aggr_id))
   echo "ID NUMBER:".$result['id'];
}  else {
   echo "<br />Could not execute statement ".$sql;
}
```

Comment: Thank you!!The query is working fine but the id value it is supposed to get from the table is not the right one.I shall look into that.As of now its giving some "Resource Id#4"

Comment: @user1597398 i have updated my answer, it will give you the insert id

Comment: i would like the corresponding id value stored in the database table rather than the insert id. :)

Comment: Is it possible for me to use this id value that is being outputted for an insert operation later??

Comment: yes, you can save this in a variable or session and use it later

Answer (score 0):

there was a syntax error look at this

```
if ($aggr_id != false)//since on success resource type is returned.
{
 echo "query 1 executed".$aggr_id;
}else  
{
  echo("<br />Could not execute statement ".$sql);
 }
```

also

```
$aggr_nr = $_REQUEST['stck_list_nr_01'].$_REQUEST['stck_list_nr_02'].$_REQUEST['stck_list_nr_03'];
echo $aggr_nr;
if(isset($aggr_nr)&&is_numeric($aggr_nr))
{
$aggr_nr=mysql_real_escape_string($aggr_nr);

$sql="SELECT v.id FROM vers_einl_aggregatnummer AS v WHERE v.aggr_nr = $aggr_nr";
$aggr_id = mysql_query($sql);
}
```

Comment: Is this supposed to be a answer?

Answer (score 0):

Just a word about PHP errors not showing (`page doesn't load up`).

You can configure PHP to stop on errors and not show it. This should be the default setting on a production server to not show too much internal information in case of an error.

You can use these lines to display all the errors, but don't forget to turn it off again ;)

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Comment: sorry, this won't help if you have a syntax error in your code as php will not execute the code / your setting.